# how can we disable the Unity Controller scripts through code

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

```
Players[i].PlayerObject.GetComponent<PrometeoCarController>().enabled = false;
```

I tried to set it as above but don't able to find it when I started the game script of another object still on

Comment: Can you add some more details and perhaps a more complete [mcve]? It isn't exactly clear what you're experiencing.

Comment: `GetComponent()` requires a type name e.g. if your controller class is called 'MyControllerScript' you'd use `GetComponent<MyControllerScript>()`

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the component actually attached and is already enabled.
Use:

```
if(Players[i].PlayerObject.GetComponent<PrometeoCarController>() && 
Players[i].PlayerObject.GetComponent<PrometeoCarController> 
().enabled)
{
   Players[i].PlayerObject.GetComponent<PrometeoCarController> 
   ().enabled = false
}
```